# Automated FaceTime audio call using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I tried to do automated facetime audio call when some event are observed in my python application. I used the code from here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189774/make-a-facetime-call-using-applescript and changed the facetime:// to facetime-audio://

```
do shell script "open facetime-audio://my_number"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "FaceTime"
   set frontmost to true
   tell window 1
       repeat while not (button "Call" exists)
           delay 1
       end repeat
       click button "Call"
   end tell
end tell
```

For the facetime video call, it worked perfectly, but for the audio call, my Mac still asked me to manually click the Call button before making any call. How do I solve this? My Mac version is 10.15.6.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the way **Apple** moved the **Call** *button* to **Notification Center**

If you change `"FaceTime"` to `"Notification Center"` in your **AppleScript** *code*, it should work.

Testing under **macOS High Sierra** and **macOS Catalina** this worked for me. Note however, in the **Preferences** of **FactTime** an **Apple ID** account needs to be enabled and already signed in for this to work properly. This is normally the case once you've signed in once and remains so between subsequent opening/closing of **FaceTime** unless you've explicitly signed out.

Comment: @JAKB824, I just now tested under **macOS Catalina** and it does indeed work, although I've updated the answer as by itself it is conditional on having already once signed in and not explicitly signed out, only closing **FaceTime** between uses as is typically normal.